# Get a return value from http.post

Tags: angularjs

My question is the following I have this code here:

```
$http.post("dologin", data).then(function(resposta)
```

When I give a console.log (response.data) it returns the following:

```
 string(40) "7f9870111b7c032f6203d144c97b8aa5a3e3f0c5"
 {"status":"success","type_user":"secretary"}
```

I need to get the "status" value. Before I was using the following and it worked fine

```
if (response.data.status === 'success') {
    if (answer.data.type_user === 'teacher') {
      $ location.path ('teacher_view');
    } else if (response.data.type_user === 'candidate') {
      $ location.path ('candidate_view');
    } else if (answer.data.type_user === 'secretary') {
      $ location.path ('secretaria_view');
    }
```

Now it does not work anymore and when I give console.log (response.data.status); it returns undefined

My backend php

```
    public function do_login(){
     $this->load->model('LoginM');
     $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $data = json_decode($request_body);
 $cpf = trim($data->cpf);
 $senha = trim($data->senha);
     $tipo = trim($data->tipo);

 $response = $this->LoginM->do_login($cpf, $senha, $tipo);

 if ($response["status"] === "success"){
        if ($tipo == 'admin') {
     $data = array(
         'logged_in' => true,
         'cod_user' => $response["cod_user"]
     );
     $message = array("status"=>"success", "tipo_user"=>"secretaria");
     }elseif ($tipo == 'professor') {
     $data = array(
         'logged_in' => true,
         'cod_professor' => $response["cod_professor"]
     );
     $message = array("status"=>"success", "tipo_user"=>"professor");
    }elseif ($tipo == 'candidato') {
     $data = array(
         'logged_in' => true,
         'cod_candidato' => $response["cod_candidato"]
     );
     $message = array("status"=>"success", "tipo_user"=>"candidato");
    }
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
 }else{
   $message = array("status"=>"error","message"=>"CPF ou senha incorretos");
 }
 echo json_encode ($message);
}
```

Test with response from console.log (response.data) and console.log (response.data.status)

[Image console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aEaO.png)

[image]

Comment: it seems that your backend is printing a string before sending the response, check if you have some code that do that in you backend. if i'm not mistaken i think that's php, right ?

Comment: Printing a message? I was using var_dump ($ password); I took it out and it continues the same way. Yes, it's php.

Comment: @AndreLacomski Can you provide screenshot of console in your question. It would make things more clear

Comment: @AndreLacomski can you add the code for your backend processing, i believe you are doing some authentication there.

Comment: @AbdelkarimELAMEL Received my feedback from the backend.

Comment: @ShashankVivek I added image

Comment: @AndreLacomski : You are not getting `JSON` in the response. You are getting a string `string(40) "7f9870111b7c032f6203d144c97b8aa5a3e3f0c5"
 {"status":"success","type_user":"secretary"}`

Comment: Check if you have an echo in `do_login` method

Comment: @ShashankVivek thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below thing should do the trick:

```
var state = JSON.parse('{'+res.data.split("{")[1]);

if (state.status === 'success') {
 if (state.type_user === 'teacher') {
  $ location.path ('teacher_view');
 } else if (state.type_user === 'candidate') {
  $ location.path ('candidate_view');
 } else if (state.type_user === 'secretary') {
  $ location.path ('secretaria_view');
}
```

But, i would strongly suggest you to fix your server response from string which you are getting right now, to the JSON which you were getting earlier